# Implement interface inside Asynctask

Tags: android, interface, android-asynctask

I don't want to implement an interface directly in asynctask class like this:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                retrofitCallBackUtil.getLastTenMessageCallBack(AppConfig.USER_ID, userId, offsetNumber, service, new RetrofitResponseCallBack() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(ArrayList<Message> messages) {
                        messageAdapter.insertToTheFirst(messages);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure() {

                    }
                });
                offsetNumber += 5;
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        }.execute();
```

I just to implement it by main class and put **this** into this parameter like this:

```
retrofitCallBackUtil.getLastTenMessageCallBack(AppConfig.USER_ID, userId, offsetNumber, service, this);
```

but I cannot do it inside asynctask method. So anyone can give me some solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have these code in `MainActivity` (or something similar).

Let's implement the interface you need to pass into `getLastTenMessageCallBack` in this Activity by `implements RetrofitResponseCallBack {...}`

Now, in your Asyntask doInBackground method, call

```
retrofitCallBackUtil.getLastTenMessageCallBack(AppConfig.USER_ID, userId, offsetNumber, service, MainActivity.this)
```

Voila, you don't have to create anonymous class inside your Asyntask anymore.
Note that, you have to move and place the `fields/params` properly, just the matter of being right place, no big deal :D

Comment: actually, all what I want is this through ChatActivity.this into that method and it run :D

Answer (score 1):

Create a class separately for `AsyncTask` like this. 
This `AsyncTask` will process the data and publish the data who implements the `interface` defined inside the `AsyncTask` . 
In this case interface defined is DataDownloadListener

```
public class GetFoldersAsync extends AsyncTask<Integer,Boolean,Boolean> {
    Context context;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    ArrayList mFolderDataLevel;

    public GetFoldersAsync(Context context){
        this.context=context;

    }
    public static interface DataDownloadListener {
        public void dataDownloadedSuccessfully(ArrayList data);
        public void dataDownloadFailed();
    }
    DataDownloadListener dataDownloadListener;
    public void setDataDownloadListener(DataDownloadListener dataDownloadListener) {
        this.dataDownloadListener = dataDownloadListener;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Please wait", "Processing.........");
    }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        Log.v(Constants.BLL_LOG, "ExplorerDBOperation doInBackground  ");

        mFolderDataLevel=new ArrayList();

        // Process to populate mFolderDataLevel

        return true;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        if(dialog!=null && dialog.isShowing())
        {dialog.dismiss();}
        Log.v(Constants.BLL_LOG, "ExplorerDBOperation onPostExecute  ");
        if(mFolderDataLevel!=null && mFolderDataLevel.size()>0){
            dataDownloadListener.dataDownloadedSuccessfully(mFolderDataLevel);
        }else{
            dataDownloadListener.dataDownloadFailed();
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the caller Activity, call this method when the AsyncTask needs to process and get back data to same activity.

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Other necessary methods goes here .....

    //call this method for processing AsyncTask and to get back data 
    public void getFolderData(int parentID, int callerID){
            Log.v(Constants.BLL_LOG,"parentID="+parentID+" , callerID="+callerID);
            mCallerID=callerID;
            GetFoldersAsync getFolders = new GetFoldersAsync(this);
            getFolders.setDataDownloadListener(new GetFoldersAsync.DataDownloadListener()
            {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                public void dataDownloadedSuccessfully(ArrayList data) {
                    Log.v(Constants.BLL_LOG,"getFolderData dataProcessSuccessfully");

                    // Success data with populated ArrayList to process further

                }
                @Override
                public void dataDownloadFailed() {
                    //Failure
                    Log.v(Constants.BLL_LOG,"getFolderData dataProcessFailed()");
                }
            });
        getFolders.execute(callerID);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but my issue is not complecated like that. Just through NameOfMyClass.this into that parameter and it was solved.